# How to open a .liquid file in a browser?

Tags: html, macos, liquid

I have html code in .liquid files. I need to open those files in a browser so I can see the code in action. How do I do that? When I try to open the .liquid file using "Open with", it disables all the browsers in the list.

Comment: As i found by doing google there is one option that you can open it by using Dreamweaver. But i am not sure because i did't try this. so you can try this and put the comments if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would open the .liquid file with a browser? It is not going to give you much info. If you need to in OSX finder - open with > other > enable - (drop down) select all applications.
If you need to see the contents of the file and the layout and placement of the tags use something like sublime text/text wrangler etc....essentially and html editor will do.